# how do I get the date in a date archive page

Tags: archives, date

In archive.php, if it is a date archive, can I get the date using a function?

Consider a url like this: myfirstsite/2013/08 - I want to get the 2013/08

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use `get_query_var()` to get the date parts:

```
$year     = get_query_var('year');
$monthnum = get_query_var('monthnum');
$day      = get_query_var('day');
```

In `wp_title()` a call to `get_query_var('m')` is used for the month too, but I got always just a `0` as value even on an URL like `/2008/09/05/`.

If you want to print the month name, use:

```
$GLOBALS['wp_locale']->get_month($monthnum);
```

The month name will be translated by WordPress then.

There are also four conditional functions you can use:

```
is_year()
is_month()
is_day()
is_date()
```